# Same table in multiple schemas

Tags: cognos

Suppose I have, on the same database, two schemas, we'll call them `Schema1` and `Schema2`. (Actually, we have 5, but the idea is the same).  In each schema, I have a table called `table1`  (again, I have about 12 tables).  To oversimplify, I want to union the two together, in a single report.  However, I don't want to have to import all these tables into Framework Manager once for each schema, set up all the joins, etc.  I can use a parameter map, which results in the report prompting me, but that only allows me to select from one schema.

Is there any way in Report Studio, within separate queries, I can hard-code the parameter, so that the report won't prompt me?  In other words, in Query1, pass in Schema1, in Query2, pass in Schema2, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're going to save by not doing this in Framework Manager, exactly.  It sounds like you just want to do the modeling work in Report Studio but won't you need to effectively do the same set of steps in a different place?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way would be to bring all the schema's tables into Framework Manager, but if the tables are all the same you could use a direct SQL query and pass parameters to that.

For example

**prompt**

(pick one from list or wherever)

schema = 'EDWDEV'

schema = 'EDWTEST'

schema = 'EDWPROD'

**qrySQL_table1**

SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM  #promptschema('schema')#.table_name

So then the same SQL query is run for whichever schema you have in the prompt